# PHP foreach loop through array which has string and array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array which has string and array.

I am trying to get the all the values with foreach. Why does it not work?

```
<?php

$shirts = array();

$shirts[101] = array(
    "size"  =>  "Large",
    "img" =>  array("images/nike1.jpg","images/nike2.jpg","images/nike3.jpg"),
    "price" => "$30";
);

$shirts[102] = array(
    "size"  =>  "Small",
    "img" =>  array("images/adidas1.jpg","images/adidas2.jpg","images/adidas3.jpg"),
    "price" => "$30";
);

$shirts[103] = array(
    "size"  =>  "Medium",
    "img" =>  array("images/puma1.jpg","images/puma2.jpg","images/puma3.jpg"),
    "price" => "$30";
);

$last = count($shirts) - 1;

foreach ($shirts as $i => $row){
    $isFirst = ($i == 0);
    $isLast = ($i == $last);

    if (is_array($row)){
        $lastChild = count($row) - 1;                       
        foreach ($row as $j =>$rowChild){
            $isFirstChild = ($j == 0);
            $isLastChild = ($j == $lastChild);                          

            echo  $rowChild;    
        }
    }else{
        echo  $row;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `I am trying to get the all the values ` what do you want at the end?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in this context? What's the behavior you're trying to correct?

Comment: I want to display all the values of the each array.

Comment: And what is happening that you don't want to have happen? Tell us what problem you want fixed, and you're likely to get a better answer

Comment: I can get display the strings in the array but cannot be shown the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach loop should be like this:

```
foreach( $shirts as $i=>$row ){

    foreach( $row as $j=>$product ){

        if( is_array( $product ) ){
            foreach( $product as $p ){
                echo $p.'<br>';
            }
        } else {
            echo $product.'<br>';
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies in this line

```
foreach ($row as $j =>$rowChild){
```

since the array inside of the "img" key is not a key value pair, this line will fail. What you want is:

```
foreach ($row as $rowChild){
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `$row` stands for:

```
array(
  "size"  =>  "Large",
  "img" =>  array("images/nike1.jpg","images/nike2.jpg","images/nike3.jpg"),
  "price" => "$30";
)
```

So `$rowChild` stands for `"Large"`, `array("images/nike1.jpg","images/nike2.jpg","images/nike3.jpg")` and `"$30"` in the loop. And in your second loop, `$j` is not int index but string index (`"size"`, `"img"` and `"price"`).

When you try to print the array, it breaks.

Comment: Thank you for kindly helping me to underdstand.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an array to string conversion error, I would look at the line where that error is likely to be triggered:

```
  echo  $rowChild;
```

If $rowChild is an array, echoing it isn't going to work. For example, if it's an array of image filenames